# Show that $f(n, k) = \binom{n}{k}$ is an onto function

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have to rigorously prove the statement:

Let $f(n, k) = \binom{n}{k}$, where $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is an onto function.

First I translated the above statement into predicate logic:

$\forall n, k \in \mathbb{N}, f(n,k) = \binom{n}{k} \implies (\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \exists x, y \in \mathbb{N}, f(x, y) = m)$.

How should I approach this proof?

Comment: $$f(n,1)=n$${[{}{[{}

Comment: You should approach it by understanding Pascal's triangle, which is the table of values of this particular function. See heropup's answer below.

Comment: Right, so I just have to say for every $n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n, 1) = n$ and therefore it is onto.

Comment: "How should I approach this proof?"  You want to prove that for every $m$ there is an $n,k$ so that ${n\choose k} = m$.  So solve that.  For any $m$ *FIND* then $n,k$ where ${n\choose k} = m$.

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\binom{n}{1} = n$$ for all $\mathbb N$, it follows that $f$ is onto:  for every $n \in \mathbb N$, the pair $(n, 1)$ is a preimage of $n$ under $f$.